# How to call MVC routes from the View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the problem where URL's are being added on the current URL for example:
Localhost/Config -> Localhost/Config/Profile
By making the call @Html.ActionLink(Resources.General.Achievements, "Index", "Profile")

When what I really want is: Localhost/Profile

I know this is possible using MVC Routes, I just can't figure out how to call them from the View. I have used Html.BeginRouteForm, but this route won't be triggered on submit.

This is my route config

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Profile",
            url: "Profile/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index" },
            namespaces: new[] { "Cobalt.Controllers" }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "Cobalt.Controllers" }
            );
```

I am trying to access the Profile controller and Index action in the root directory. I have both Config and Manage Areas, which I am trying to escape from when making calls back to controllers in the root directory.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What are current routes you defined? Please specify what is your controller and action. Then specify what url you want to match.

Comment: I updated my question for you.

Comment: You want `@Html.RouteLink()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with areas, if you want to move from one area to another area or out of an area into the root, you can use the overload of ActionLink which allows you to specify route data and pass an empty string (or the appropriate area name) into area:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Resources.General.Achievements, "Index", "Profile", new { area = string.Empty })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [RouteLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
@Html.RouteLink(Resources.General.Achievements, "Profile", new { id = "1234" })
```

Do note that since your "id" parameter is not declared optional on your Profile route it won't match unless you supply it.

Comment: Both of your solutions work, but I would like to avoid defining multiple routes just to move through areas if possible. I've since figured out my problem was more around the areas than the routes. Thanks though!